# DirectInput SetDataFormat error

Tags: directinput

I want to write a program interacting with joystick. I am using a standard SDK example and dinput8.lib.

Here's the code. GUID Is taken from enumJoysticksCallback function. I throw away everything to minimise chance of error.

```
LPDIRECTINPUT8          g_pDI = NULL;
LPDIRECTINPUTDEVICE8    g_pJoystick = NULL;

HRESULT hr = DirectInput8Create ( GetModuleHandle( NULL ), DIRECTINPUT_VERSION, IID_IDirectInput8, (void**)&g_pDI, NULL );

    GUID  *GUID_Saitek = new _GUID ;
    GUID_Saitek->Data1 = 0xA00DBD70;
    GUID_Saitek->Data2 = 0x7FB5;
    GUID_Saitek->Data3 = 0x11E3;
    char tmp[8] = { 0x80, 0x3, 0x44, 0x45, 0x53, 0x54, 0x0, 0x0 };
    memcpy(GUID_Saitek->Data4, tmp, 8);

    g_pDI->CreateDevice( *GUID_Saitek, &g_pJoystick, NULL );
    hr = g_pJoystick->SetDataFormat( &c_dfDIJoystick2 ) ;
```

Program fails on this string

```
hr = g_pJoystick->SetDataFormat( &c_dfDIJoystick2 );
```

hr returns 0x80070216 which seems to be ERROR_ARITHMETIC_OVERFLOW.

&c_dfDIJoystick instead of &c_dfDIJoystick2 does not help too.

For mouse it is the same...

```
LPDIRECTINPUT8          di = NULL;
LPDIRECTINPUTDEVICE8    Mouse = NULL;
HRESULT hr = DirectInput8Create(GetModuleHandle( NULL ),  DIRECTINPUT_VERSION, IID_IDirectInput8,  (VOID**)&di, NULL);
hr = di->CreateDevice( GUID_SysMouse, &Mouse, NULL );
hr = Mouse->SetDataFormat( &c_dfDIMouse ) ;
```

hr returns 0x80070216 again
The example application "Joystick.exe" works no problem.

GetCapabilities returns some random stuff which is definately not true

- Embarcadero RAD Studio XE5/Borland CPP Builder 6 (both have same
  results)
- DirectInput Saitek Rudder Pedals/Saitek X52 controllers    (both
  crash program)
- 32bit app
- standard SDK example "Joystick"

What is wrong? Error does not match anything related to directinput. Device creates with no errors but any work with it leads to errors.

Thanks!

UPDATE: SetCooperativeLevel function returns 0x80070006 which is ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out what was the problem. It lied here: &c_dfDIJoystick2

For some reason Microsoft attached pre-defined structures that do not match anythig. Even &c_dfDIMouse does not match my simple 3 button mouse.
The answer came with another sample code "Custom Format". 
You have to make a new format structure for each device because even EnumObjects function will not make it for you, which makes DirectInput quite inconvenient.